# How to use MCMC sampling on a custom function with TensorFlow Probability

Tags: tensorflow, probability

I'm just starting on TensorFlow and I am unsure how I can sample from a custom probability distributions that is not easily expressible as a composition of the stock distributions.

How can I use a custom function for `target_log_prob` input for MCMC samplers?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you need. Still, I recommend the [bayesian hackers book](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers) for learning some techniques (the TFP chapters). Also the official docs are another great source.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @WillianFuks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any `target_log_prob_fn` to the `tfp.mcmc.HamiltonianMonteCarlo` `TransitionKernel`, as long as it computes a value proportional to your target density (and is differentiable with respect to its inputs). E.g.

```
def target_log_prob_fn(x):
  return -.5 * x ** 2
```

is a perfectly valid target log prob function. If you want to sample multiple chains in parallel you'll need to take care that your target is "batch-friendly". For example, if you need to `reduce_sum` over some part of the state (say for a multivariate distribution), be sure to be explicit about which axes you're summing over

```
def target_log_prob_fn(x):
  return -.5 * tf.reduce_sum(x ** 2, axis=-1)  # don't sum over chains!

...

tfp.mcmc.sample_chain(
    kernel,
    num_burnin_steps=100,
    num_results=100,
    current_state=tf.zeros(10, 5),   # 10 parallel chains of 5-D variables
)
```

HTH!